# SharpDX SwapChain1 AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, directx, direct3d, sharpdx

So I try to create a SwapChain1 in SharpDX.

Here is the Code:

```
            SwapChainDescription1 desc = new()
            {
                Width = toSetSize.Value.Width,
                Height = toSetSize.Value.Height,
                Format = Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm,
                Stereo = false,
                SampleDescription = new SampleDescription(1, 0),
                Usage = Usage.BackBuffer | Usage.RenderTargetOutput,
                BufferCount = 1,
                Scaling = Scaling.Stretch,
                SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard
            };

            SwapChainFullScreenDescription scd = new SwapChainFullScreenDescription()
            {
                RefreshRate = new Rational(60, 1),
                Scaling = DisplayModeScaling.Stretched,
                Windowed = false
            };

            using (var dxgiDevice2 = device.QueryInterface<SharpDX.DXGI.Device2>())
            using (var dxgiAdapter = dxgiDevice2.Adapter)
            using (var dxgiFactory2 = dxgiAdapter.GetParent<SharpDX.DXGI.Factory2>())
            {
                res = new SwapChain1(dxgiAdapter.GetParent<SharpDX.DXGI.Factory2>(), device, Window.Handle, ref desc, scd);
                return res;
            }
```

my issue is, this code throws a AccessViolationException with the Attempted to read or write corrupted memory stuff.

What am i doing wrong?

How can i fix this?

I tried:

Changing the Parameters inside of "desc" and "scd"

Edit: So i got a step further, seemingly factory.NativePointer was IntPtr.Zero, i have updated the code, hope this helps...

Edit2: Okay one step closer, again, i enabled Debugging from native code and got this:

```
        Exception called at 0x759CE292 in Demo.exe: Microsoft C++ Exception: _com_error at location 0x0297C5B8.
        Exception called at 0x6BA81D22 (dxgi.dll) in Demo.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation at position 0x000000B8.
```

Untranslated (german):

```
        Ausnahme ausgelöst bei 0x759CE292 in Demo.exe: Microsoft C++-Ausnahme: _com_error bei Speicherort 0x0297C5B8.
        Ausnahme ausgelöst bei 0x6BA81D22 (dxgi.dll) in Demo.exe: 0xC0000005: Zugriffsverletzung beim Lesen an Position 0x000000B8.
```

Comment: Please share a Minimal, Reproducible Example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @SimonMourier isnt the code i added enough?

Comment: There's no reason a priori why an error would happen, so, no, it's not enough.